# How can I load comment IDs using the comment type?

Tags: 8, comments

I know how to load comment ids for a particular node by following code

```
$entity_manager = \Drupal::entityTypeManager();
$cids = $entity_manager
    ->getStorage('comment')
    ->getQuery('AND')
    ->condition('entity_id', '25364')
    ->condition('entity_type', 'node')
    ->execute();
```

But I need one more condition to add on because this node might have multiple comment type linked. I know the machine name , but I don't know exactly what should be the first parameter to be passed in condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I itself got the answer i just guessed the name to be passed in condition.

```
$cids = $entity_manager
    ->getStorage('comment')
    ->getQuery('AND')
    ->condition('entity_id', '25364')
    ->condition('entity_type', 'node')
    ->condition('comment_type' 'post_trp_comments')
    ->execute();
```